# Big O of String repetition append in Java

Tags: java, big-o, stringbuilder

I have a function to get a a string as a repetition of an original string. I'm wondering if I use StringBuilder append, what is the Big O of the function? Is it O(nl) : n is number of repeats and l is length of the original string ?

```
public String getRepetition(String originalStr, Integer n){
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str.append(originalStr);
    return str.toString();
}
```

Comparing with the approach below, which one is better?

```
public String getRepetition(String originalStr, Integer n){
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str += originalStr;
    return originalStr;
}
```

Comment: I bet this is a duplicate of a highly rated question. Or perhaps "everyone knows" the canonical Java O(n^2) example so have never asked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why other three answers are all saying both pieces of code are O(n). Assuming `originalStr` is not `""`, the first is O(n) the other O(n^2)! (That's an exclamation, not a factorial.) They teach this on the first day of Java school. C programmers get "don't use `strlen` in the condition of that `for` loop"; Java programmers get this.

```
String str = "";
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    str += originalStr;
```

Each time around this loop `str` is getting longer. It's `i * orginalStr.length()`. Creating a new `String` (assuming no *wild* compiler optimisations) which takes time roughly proportional to `i` each time.

**Edit:** Usually we ignore the length of the original string. But yeah, of course it's going to be proprotional, so O(n*strlen(originalStr)) and O(n*n*strlen(originalStr)). By convention this is dealt with separately.

If we rewrite the code without the `String` abstraction, perhaps it will be clearer.

```
public static char[] getRepetition(char[] originalStr, int n) {
    char[] str = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        assert str.length == i * originalStr.length;
        char[] newStr = new char[str.length + originalStr.length];
        for (int j=0; j<str.length; ++j) {
            newStr[j] = str[j];
        }
        for (int j=0; j<originalStr.length; ++j) {
            newStr[str.length+j] = originalStr[j];
        }
        str = newStr;
    }
    return str;
}
```

(As ever, I've not bothered to so much as compile the code. Not safe to use in a nuclear reactor.)

Just for giggles, let's deabstract the first implementation.

```
public static char[] getRepetition(char[] originalStr, int n) {
    char[] str = new char[16];
    int strLen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        assert strLen == i * originalStr.length;
        // ensureCapacity
        if (str.length < strLen + originalStr.length) {
            // The size at least doubles, 
            //   so this happens increasing less often.
            // It wont happen again for approximately
            //   the same number of iterations
            //   as have already happened!
            char[] newStr = new char[Math.min(
                str.length + originalStr.length, // first time safe
                str.length*2 + 2                 // *2 !
            )];
            for (int j=0; j<strLen; ++j) {
                newStr[j] = str[j];
            }
            str = newStr;
        }
        // actual append
        for (int j=0; j<originalStr.length; ++j) {
            str[strLen++] = originalStr[j];
        }
    }
    // toString
    char[] newStr = new char[strLen];
    for (int i=0; j<newStr.length; ++i) {
         newStr[i] = str[j];
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Comment: You're correct, of course. The missing context is **what** growth rate is being asked about. The **number of iterations** of the `+=` loop is *O(n)* but the **time** taken grows by *O(n^2)*. Usually big-O is about time, and somewhat less often about space. Number of iterations is often proportional to time, but only when iteration time remains constant. This isn't true in this case, because each successive iteration is more expensive.

Comment: I've seen people make a similar mistake when replacing an element-copying for-loop with `System.arraycopy`. The claim is that the complexity is reduced from (say) *O(n)* to *O(1)*. Using `arraycopy` is indeed much faster, since it's highly tuned, native, and often vectorized code. But "much faster" doesn't imply a reduction in complexity; `arraycopy` still has to copy *n* elements.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your approaches are `O(n)` while the first approach eliminates several temporary `String`(s). It isn't clear why you have made `n` an `Integer`, nor why you have not made this a `static` method (it depends on no instance state). Additionally, in Java 8+, you could implement it with a lambda like

```
public static String getRepetition(String originalStr, int n) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> originalStr).limit(n).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Also, if you're going to use a `StringBuilder` as in your first example, you can explicitly size it to avoid having to amortize the cost of resizing the `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(originalStr.length() * n);
```

Answer (score 1):

In both the cases the complexity is `O(n)` because you are iterating `n` times.

The only difference in second approach is you are creating new `String` in each iteration i.e. at `str += originalStr;`